# Square Bracket Size Mismatch

Tags: brackets

I have a continued fraction surrounded by square brackets of unequal size. I want them to be of equal size. I've tried the `\delimitershortfall` set to a negative value. I've tried `\Bigg` for the right-hand side as opposed just `\big` for the left-hand side. Any suggestions to make the brackets of equal size greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\big{\lfloor \frac{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+.....}}}}{\frac{f_{10}}{f_9}} \Bigg{\rfloor}}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the continued fraction use `\cfrac`; then enclose the big fraction in `gathered` so that it will be vertically centered, so `\left\lfloor` and `\right\rfloor` will do their job properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\lfloor
\!\begin{gathered}
\frac{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\dotsb}}}}
     {\dfrac{f_{10}}{f_9}}
\end{gathered}
\right\rfloor
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your `\big{\lfloor...}` works just by accident. Use `\bigl\lfloor` for opening and `\bigr\rfloor` for closing (or the `\Bigl`-`\Bigr` and so on variants). While `\bigl{\lfloor}` works, `\left{\lfloor}` definitely won't.

Comment: Your solution is better; I've deleted my answer.